# Cancellation Law, If $ax=ay$ then $x=y$

Tags: arithmetic

It's about cancellation law.

if $ax=ay$ then $x=y$, provided that $a \neq 0$

It says that this only true if it applied in whole integers not just positive integers, I'm not really sure, if I put some numbers it turns that $x \neq y$ after all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide the examples?

Comment: It's weird question. The cancellation law stated above is true for real and even complex numbers. If you think it fails sometimes, have you tried to find a counterexample to disprove it?

Comment: Really sorry, I'm not reading the text carefully, the statement above is correct, my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ax=ay$ so $a(x-y)=0$, so because $a\neq 0$ we get $x=y$.

This is true whenever $a\cdot b = 0 \Rightarrow a = 0 $ or $b = 0$, so it works for positive integers as well as for negative integers.

Comment: Thanks, I can understand more from you answer.

Comment: A good observation is that $a.b=0 \implies a=0$ or $b=0$ is actually equivalent to $ax=ay \implies x=y$ if $a\neq 0$